# Android Studio error when opening existing project

Tags: flutter

I am currently trying to run an existing project in Android Studio ,but when I loaded the project in my android studio ,it gives me error, which is target url does not exist error. How should I fix this problem ,because i just cloned the whole project using the url.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dwFu3.png)

Since i cloned the project,the packages should all be there,but it gives me error for most of the import package lines.
I am not sure if the get dependencies can solve ,but i did not find it or there is another method can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the top menu of the Android Studio and, Build -> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your dependencies are not installed
Fire a terminal and type

```
pub get
```

Maybe this would solve the problem or try

```
flutter pub cache repair
```

Answer (score 0):

first is open your flutter project, and call

```
flutter clean

flutter doctor
```

[image]

right click on android studio, then open Android studio, this way(not directly by folder)

[image]

Comment: Hi.It seems like i did not see the Flutter optional in my tool menu ,but i am sure i have flutter plugin.

Comment: if your flutter project run proper in android device or emulator, then surely this option also you have in project.check again

Comment: I don't think it can run properly in emulator ,coz if i run it ,it gives me error,which is about the url .